# Nine divs in columns. How to design this?

Tags: html, css

I have nine divs like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="example">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to arrange them as shown in the picture?(css)

[image]

Comment: Ah the perfect image of an ideal case that webdesigners always send to me... What happens if one block is 1 line taller or shorter? Do these blocks need to be arranged in columns or should headings stay on the same line?

Comment: @FelipeAls: You are right, headings should stay on the same line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways, 1st...

Use `display: inline-block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwnRU/)

```
.wrap {
    width: 950px;
}

#content {
    display: inline-block; /* Can also use floats, depends on you */
    width: 300px;
}
```

2nd using `column-count` property (This is not widely supported yet)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwnRU/1/) (Demo may look weird a bit, you need to use CSS reset)

```
.wrap {
    column-count: 3; /* This will cut your content in 3 pieces */
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: You should mention column-count is strictly CSS 3, but good thinking.

Comment: `(This is not widely supported yet)` :)

Comment: Yeah you said that but if you say it's CSS 3 specifically I just think you're more complete / less vague :)

Comment: CSS3 is made of proprietary MS thing that became standard (`@font-face` is IE4+), well supported (`border-radius` IE9+) while grid layout is IE10 only (may become Template)... and ruby and speech are errrr. With the modular nature of CSS3 (a good thing by many aspects) comes a few problems. Sites like caniuse.com are very useful when it comes to using these features.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/okamaw/4/)**

---

Like this:

```
#content {
  width:800px; /* adjust width to accommodate three colums */
  /* your other styles */
}

.example {
  width: 150px;  /* adjust width */
  float:left;
}

.clear{ clear:both; }
```

You should adjust the `width` of container and 9 divs as per your needs.

After each set of three divs, you should use a div `clear:both` (or search for **clearfix** on google for as alternative) like this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

HTML

```
<div class="left">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
</div>

<div class="middle">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
   float: left;
   width: 33%;
}
.middle{
   width: 33%;
}
.right{
   float: right;
   width: 33%;
}
.clear{
   clear:both;
}
```

Hope this helps? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on what width you want your content in, but I'd make content into a class, make 3 content divs, and put 3 example divs in each. Then, just set a %age width on the example divs and float them left. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkDTS/) to demonstrate.

css:

```
.example {
    width: 33.33333%;
    float: left;
}
```

markup:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="example">
        <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```